# Deciding between parallel network calls vs event-driven data synching in microservices

Tags: microservices

On the product page(as shown in the image) we are showing and hiding options based on microservice response. All these microservice calls are parallel and don't cause any latency issues(so far).

[image]

This is how microservices are structured.

**Make, Model, Varients** shown in the menu are powered from **Product** microservice

**Product Images, Videos, 360 views, News, Road Tests** are powered from **CMS** microservice

**Product rating, reviews** are powered from **ProductReviews** microservice

Now, something that needs to be noticed here is that every individual thing is a network call to respective microservice. We are making around 9 network calls(parallel) to above microservices to power content on the product page.

Here are the questions...

1. **Should continue with multiple parallels calls as they are not causing any latency issues?**
2. **Should we think of reducing network calls by combining requests of each microservice into 1?** ex: combine multiple service calls to CMS into 1 and do the same for the other two microservices. This way we will be reducing the number of network calls from 9 to 3
3. **Should be sync this data to Product microservice through the event-driven system?** This looks most optimised approach considering read throughput. But implementing event-driven system worth it?

Please help us decide the right approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's too much network calls for this page.

**1) Should continue with multiple parallels calls as they are not causing any latency issues?**

I believe these are too many calls.

**2)Should we think of reducing network calls by combining requests of each micro service into 1?**

I think yes. There are couple of reason.

**Slower connections**
If network speed is good then you may not feel it , but for mobile users this could be too much. Also the bandwidth is very important when it comes to slower networks. Watch out for that

**Security**
The more API calls you have the more attack surface you expose.

**Adding more APIs**
If you add more APIs you may have to change client and server both.  But with consolidated response you have less work to do.

**3) Should be sync this data to Product microservice through the event-driven system?**

Well depends. Materialized views works great when your read only queries are too high (which is your case). When your user base will grow,  you may eventually need to get to this approach.